# @Secured and @PreAuthorize work fine in Controller but not working in Service level

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

What could be the problem ? 
When I use this annotation in my controller, it works fine, the page is only accessible for a ROLE_USER

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
```

This annotation works also :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
```

When I move the same annotation to my Service, it doesn't work, the method is accessible without having the ROLE_USER role !! 
I'm testing Spring Security, My Service is just a test (TestService interface and its implementation), whether I put the annotation in the interface or in the implementation level, as if the annotation doesn't exist.

This is my dispatcher-servlet.xml file :

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
<bean id="TestService" class="myPackage.TestServiceImpl"/>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Make sure that the context that has the services in has the `<sec:enable-global-method-security />` tag else it won't work.

Comment: I did that : '<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>' or '<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>' ! It works in my Controller, the problem is not here !!

Comment: Trust me it is... AOP only works for the beans in the same application context, it doesn't apply to beans defined in parent and child contexts. Make sure that the instance of the service you are using is the one you expect to be using (make sure you don't scan for beans twice for instance).

Answer (score 0):

As [@M. Deinum said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048147/secured-and-preauthorize-work-fine-in-controller-but-not-working-in-service-le#comment46335886_29048147), the problem is that your `enable-global-method-security` is only in the DispatchereServlet's context, but not in the ContextLoaderListener's (which is a parent of the other one). Your service beans probably belong to ContextLoaderListener context, and your controllers to DispatchereServlet. As [@M. Deinum mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048147/secured-and-preauthorize-work-fine-in-controller-but-not-working-in-service-le#comment46336748_29048147), `@Secured` and `@PreAuthorize` are AOP based and work only withing the same context where `enable-global-method-security` is.

**TL;DR** Add `sec:enable-global-method-security` to ContextLoaderListener's context (might be a param called `contextConfigLocation` in your web.xml).

Comment: But I tried to put my Service bean and security:enable-global-security in the same context (dispacther-servlet.xml) (as in the question) but it didn't work ! Puting enable-global-security twice generates a IllegalStateException exception in my application ! As I said, it is working know but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact similar problem and I have solved by injecting the Service/Component/Repository.

I have a working example here: 
https://github.com/lfoppiano/spring-security-j2ee-preauth-example